# Inequalities: A Mathematical Olympiad Approach (Exercise 1.17)

Tags: inequality

[image]

**My attempt**:

Since $a>0\Rightarrow-a<0\Rightarrow1-a<1\Rightarrow c(1-a)<c$. Thus, ${1\over 4}<c(1-a)<c$. Similarily ${1\over 4}<a(1-b)<a$ and ${1\over 4}<b(1-c)<b$. On adding these inequalities, we get: ${3\over 4}<-(ab+bc+ca)<0$, which is a contradiction. Hence all the three inequalities cannot hold at the same time.

Is this proof correct? I am asking this because my method is quite different from that given by the author in the solutions.Also I am new to Inequalities.

Comment: It's not clear how you are adding - you get $3/4<(a+b+c)-(ab+ac+bc)<a+b+c$.

Comment: Your proof is incorrect, cos you subtracted a b and c from middle and right expression but you didn't from the left

Answer (score 2):

if the inequalities are true. then $$a,b,c$$ are less than $1$ and $$a(1-b)b(1-c)c(1-a)>\frac{1}{64}$$ But since $$x(1-x)\le \frac{1}{4}$$ for $$0\le x\le 1$$ then $$a(1-b)b(1-c)c(1-a)\le \frac{1}{64}$$